# Angular-Chartjs not loading until I leave the page and come back

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I am using angular-chartjs but the graphs are not loading the data until after leaving the page and coming back. A refresh is not enough for the graph to load you have to leave the page and come back.

Does anyone know what could possibly cause this? I have been over all the set up documents numerous times. The console shows no errors and the network table shows all my dependencies/sources where loaded with a 200 okay status.

Comment: Have you looked at your console / network console to check out if or what is happening? I feel like this question is too vague to answer because it could be a very broad set of reasons. I would recommend narrowing down possible problems first.

Comment: Hi @Bricktop I think you are right about me being vague but im really not sure where to start looking for a solution. I tried using dev tools to see what was going on in the network tab but nothing jumped out as looking off and likewise with the console. I'm just hoping someone might have had a similar problem

Comment: The issue you described appears (in my experience) if you get your data for the chart/graph from an API or something similar and doesn't get resolved properly. Have you tried if the same issue occurs with static data or is your data static?

Comment: Originally i was using google analytics data but now to debug I have switched to using static data --I just copy and pasted the data points from the docs in case it was an ajax error (or something similar).

Comment: At this point it is probably a good idea for you to try and create a plnkr or fiddle that replicates your problem, there is a high possibility you find your problem by doing that already. I sadly have no more ideas without actually seeing code / the behaviour.
Edit: maybe check in a different browser to make sure it's not a browser issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help Bricktop I will try that. Its a big project though so im not sure how well I will be able to replicate it. Its worth the try though! thanks again